# Definite integral involving bessel functions of first and second kind

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, special-functions, generating-functions

Is there any standard solution of the integral:
 $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^{a} J_m(k_1\rho)Y_m(k_2\rho)\rho \, d\rho$. where the integer $m\geq0$ and $a<\infty$

Comment: You can try searching the collection at [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22)

Answer (score 2):

For example, from  [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22), equation 10.22.4, if $k_1^2 \ne k_2^2$,
$$
\int \rho\,J_m\left(k_1\rho\right)Y_m(k_2\rho)d\rho=\frac{\rho\left[k_1 J_{m+1}\left(k_1\rho\right)Y_m(k_2\rho)-k_2 J_m\left(k_1\rho\right)%
Y_{m+1}(k_2\rho)\right]}{k_1^{2}-k_2^{2}},
$$